# extracting HTTP post data

Tags: c, string, http, post, memory

I have another problem. Now I'm trying to write a function that can successfully extract post data from a standard HTTP header.

For example, if my incoming HTTP header is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com

postdata=1&otherdata=2&whatever=3
```

I want to retrieve only:

```
postdata=1&otherdata=2&whatever=3
```

To comply with standards, `\r\n` must be produced in code to indicate a new line.

Currently, the function returns nothing, but if I remove `&& !strstr(p1,"\r\n")` then every line in the HTTP header except for the first line is returned.

The function parameters from left to right are: incoming HTTP data, output data, and maximum size to retrieve.

I would then call the function from another program in the following way:

```
char result[500];
char* httppostdata=gethttpdata();
gethttppost(httppostdata,result,500);
```

We have to assume above that gethttpdata returns a valid pointer to the actual HTTP data.

This is the function that needs fixing:

```
unsigned long gethttppost(char* in,char* res,unsigned long max){
  char *p2,*p1=in;unsigned long mx;
  while ((p1=strstr(p1,"\r\n"))){
    p1+=2;
    if ((p2=strstr(p1,"\r\n\r\n")) && !strstr(p1,"\r\n")){
      mx=(unsigned long)(p2-p1);
      if (mx > max){mx=max;}
      memcpy(res,p1,mx);
      return mx;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your HTTP header always contain the word `postdata`?

Comment: not always. It may be random

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can adapt this to your needs. It uses `strtok` to find the last token in the string delimited by `CR` and/or `LF`. It does not matter if the terminating `CRLF` is absent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char httphdr[]=
      "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\npostdata=1&otherdata=2&whatever=3\r\n";
    char *ptr = NULL, *lptr = NULL;
    ptr = strtok(httphdr, "\r\n");
    while (ptr) {
        lptr = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
    }
    if (lptr)
        printf("%s\n", lptr);
    else
        printf("Not found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
postdata=1&otherdata=2&whatever=3
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think strtok works for 64-bit systems.

Comment: @Mike: why wouldn't it?  It won't work for wide characters, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @Mike why not try it? Your partially successful attempt used `strstr` and these string functions don't need any particular sized system to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
    if ((p2=strstr(p1,"\r\n\r\n")) && !strstr(p1,"\r\n")){
```

If `p2` is not `NULL`, there is a `"\r\n"`sequence for sure, and the second `strstr` cannot possibly return `NULL`. So the code skips the end of headers, and after that the first `strstr` always fails.

I don't see the reason for these complications. You only need to find (once) where the headers end:

```
    char * headers_end = strstr(in, "\r\n\r\n");
    if (headers_end == 0)
        return 0;
    char * body = headers_end += 4;
    char * body_end = strstr(body, "\r\n");
    ....
```